# Is there a general solution to $ \int{f \cdot g } $ if I know that $ \dfrac{d^n}{dx^n}f = $ c$ \cdot f $ $, $ for some $n \in \mathbb{N} $

Tags: integration

These type of integrals seem to pop up a lot in physics and it got me wondering whether a closed form expression exists, even if it has some limitations (only for even n-s for example ). I'm asking about integrals that are usually evaluated by repeated application of integration by parts, like $$ \int \sin(x) \cdot e^x dx$$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that $f$ is $n$-times differentiable and satisfies $f^{(n)}=cf$ for some $c\in\mathbb{C}$ then applying integration by parts $n$ times gives
\begin{align}
&\int f(x)\cdot e^x\mathrm{d}x\\
&=e^x\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^kf^{(k)}(x)+(-1)^nc\int f(x)e^x\mathrm{d}x\end{align}
which implies that
\begin{align}
&\int f(x)\cdot e^x\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{e^x}{1-(-1)^nc}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^kf^{(k)}(x)+\text{constant}
\end{align}

Comment: This does not require that  $ g(x) = e^x $, right?

Comment: @JohnyO42 I don't really see what result you are expecting to achieve if $g(x)\ne e^x$ as one would not necessarily be able to integrate $g(x)$.

Comment: Somewhat more generally, you might consider $g(x) = e^{rx}$.

Comment: Of course,  $f^{(n)} = c f$ (for $c \ne 0$) implies $f(x)$ is a linear combination of $e^{\omega x}$ where $\omega$ are the complex $n$'th roots of $c$.